# Insert into a third table from two other tables with one to many relationship

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join, sql-insert

I have 3 tables:

1st table - `Students`:

```
| ID       | NAME     |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | Student-1|
| 2        | Student-2|
| 3        | Student-3|
```

2nd table - `Homework`:

```
| ID       | NAME     |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | Homework-1|
| 2        | Homework-2|
| 3        | Homework-3|
```

I would like to insert each [ID from Students] to certain [ID from Homework] in 3rd Table. In the end, the 3rd table should looks like this:

3rd table - `Teacher_Board`:

```
| Student_ID | Homework_ID   |
| --------   | ------------- |
| 1          | 1             |
| 2          | 1             |
| 3          | 1             |
```

My SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO `teacher_board` (`student_id`, `homework_id`) 
    SELECT `id` 
    FROM `homework` 
    INNER JOIN `students` ON `students.id` = `teacher_board.student_id` 
    WHERE `id` = 1
```

Comment: its not clear what you try to achieve. in your result set homework id 3 times 1 for each strudent, is it correct? or it should be each homework map to each student?

Comment: Yep, my mistake. 1 Homework for each student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select two columns and use a CROSS JOIN

```
INSERT INTO `teach_board` (`student_id`,`homework_id`) 

SELECT
s.id , h.id
FROM `homework` CROSS JOIN  `students`
WHERE h.id =  1
```

A better approach woudl to be add all new columns that not exist in the table before, so you can run it every time you insert new rows in hmework

```
INSERT INTO `teach_board` (`student_id`,`homework_id`)
SELECT s.`id` , h.id
FROM `homework` CROSS JOIN `students`
WHERE NOt EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM  `teach_board` WHERE  `student_id` = s.id AND `homework_id` = h.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a join here - nor for temporary tables.

You want to insert a fixed homework value, so we can insert/select directly from the students table:

```
INSERT INTO `teacher_board` (`student_id`, `homework_id`) 
SELECT `id`, 1 FROM `student`
```

This inserts one row for each student, with homework 1.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, [name] varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @t1(name) SELECT ('Student1') UNION select ('Student2') UNION select ('Student3')
--SELECT * FROM @t1

DECLARE @t2 TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY  IDENTITY (1,1), [name] varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @t2(name) SELECT ('Homework-1') UNION SELECT ('Homework-2') UNION SELECT ('Homework-3')
--SELECT * FROM @t2

SELECT * FROM @t1 CROSS APPLY @t2
```

[image]

Comment: just want to clarify difference between cross apply and cross join: "a join relies on self-sufficient sets of data, i.e. sets should not depend on each other. On the other hand, CROSS APPLY is only based on one predefined set and can be used with another separately created set. A worked example should help with understanding this difference."